# Netbeans JTree Linestyle

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm having difficulties removing the "lineStyle" lines in JTrees using Netbeans.  In a standalone program, I'm able to do this:

```
    JTree myJTree = new JTree();
    myJTree.putClientProperty("JTree.lineStyle", "None");

    JScrollPanel myScrollPanel = new JScrollPanel();
    myScrollPanel.setViewportView(myJTree);
```

But when I try adding that code into my Netbeans created GUI, I get what appears to be a "Windows Default" linestyle.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's your UI set to and where do you set it?  Netbeans tends to automatically assume System UI I think.  But I'm  not sure if it actually adds code to enforce that.  You might try setting a different UI in your main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans sets it own system-wide UI.

You can fix this by overriding setUI or updateUI methods on your JTree, where in addition to calling super implementation method you would do your client property setting.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the following removes the lines from JTrees globally in Swing

```
UIManager.put("Tree.paintLines", Boolean.FALSE);
```

(Not sure how this interacts with NetBeans though, sorry.)