# JTree Line Style and Nimbus

Tags: java, swing, jtree, nimbus

I am using the Nimbus look and feel. According to this [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display), you should be able to achieve 3 different line styles with your JTree:

[image]

While using the following code:

```
theTree.putClientProperty("JTree.lineStyle", "Horizontal");
```

My JTree looks like this:

[image]

It has the "None" style and not the "Horizontal" style. Any idea why this might be? Does it have something to do with Nmbus? Do I need to call something special after setting that property?

Thanks

Comment: @Stack Yes I am. However my JTree is custom. It doesn't use the GUI editor.

Comment: I'm not sure then. Check out this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347607/netbeans-jtree-linestyle). The recommendation is to override setUI and updateUI.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe Nimbus supports the `JTree.lineStyle` property. Only the MetalLookAndFeel does.

Take a look at the source code for `javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTreeUI` (which is used by Nimbus) and `MetalTreeUI` (which is used by Metal).

Change to MetalLookAndFeel and see if it works.

Comment: Interesting. I did change it to Metal LaF and it did work. Kind of a let down that Nimbus doesnt support them

Comment: I have tried to do this with Nimbus before and could not find a way that Nimbus supported it.  I agree with dogbane's answer.

Comment: @eugener No I havent. Could you provide any links or details?

Comment: In short... you create your own tree cell renderer by inheriting from existing and overriding paint method to draw the line or putting default renderer JLabel component on the panel and adding separator to the bottom of the panel. Here is a link from Swing tutorial about tree cell renederers (scroll down a bit):http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display

Let me know if you need more info on that.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out you can get some of this effect by doing

```
NimbusLookAndFeel laf = new NimbusLookAndFeel();
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
nimbUID = laf.getDefaults();
nimbUID.put("Tree.drawHorizontalLines", true);
nimbUID.put("Tree.drawVerticalLines", true);
```

Not perfect, but close.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still interested in this:

The following snippet is working for me.

```
NewNimbusLookAndFeel laf = new NewNimbusLookAndFeel();

UIDefaults defs = laf.getDefaults();
defs.put("Tree.drawHorizontalLines", true);
defs.put("Tree.drawVerticalLines", true);
defs.put("Tree.linesStyle", "dashed");

try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
} catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
    //Error handling code
}
```